# copying old object attributes ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, activerecord, clone

Hi want to copy few attributes of old object and create new object with few changed attributes . I am using rails version 3.0.7 hence i am not able to use old_object.dup. I don't want to use old_object.clone because it gives me shallow copy of the record, including copying the frozen state. Hence I follow following method

```
@old_product = Product.find(params[:id])

@product = Product.create(@old_product.attributes.merge({:description => params[:product][:description], :category => params[:product][:box_id], :user_id => current_user.id}))
```

but It gives me error user can not be blank. In fact it not storing my description and category as well. Is this the right way to do this. Any another way to copy attributes of old object and change few of them.

Comment: I am able to change category attribute and description but not able to change user_id. Even it not copying user_id attribute from old_product object. It showing nil value....

Comment: Is the user_id field a whitelisted attribute in the Product model, so you can mass-assign it?

Comment: Hye Agis I just answered my question and you are right I added it into accessible lists of attributes and now its working thank you for quick reply ...

Comment: the dup method is supported rails 2.0.0 onwards. see http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/dup

Answer (score 0):

I got it ... in product model **:user_id** is now added into **atr_accessible**. Initially I am not able to access that attributes hence it is not updating or changing that attribute in new_object.
now it's working fine.

Comment: Can you mark my answer as accepted and upvote it then? Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/a/12844015/1242778

Answer (score 0):

You'd better not set the `attr_accessible :user_id`. It will be a vulnerability in your system, and anyone can change the value with mass assignment. Rather assign it manually in this code or use some cloning function and change the other properties.

Answer (score 0):

A messy solution would be adding `attr_accessible :user_id` to your model, although it's not recommended since it's going to make your application vulnerable to Mass Assignment exploitation.

If you're going to use it in development for a while it's fine though.